# Sort Datagridview, with numbers as strings

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I am adding numeric (integer) values to a datagridview. The numbers are coming from a database as decimal but I am outputting them to the grid with x.toString("N2") to format them with commas. When I do this, they no longer sort numerically when clicking on the column header. They sort alpahbetically instead. Is there a way to display them with the comma and still have them sort numerically?

Comment: What about adding another hidden column to your datasource with the numeric value specifically for ordering?

Comment: Why are you converting to string those values? Just set the `Format` property of the Column to `N2`.

Comment: My grid is not bound to a datasource. the rows are added manually after the data is read from the DB. I want the user to sort the columns at will by clicking on the header.

Comment: So what? Set the `ValueType` of the Column to `decimal` and `Format` to `N2`.

Comment: -Jimi, how do I do that? I do not see a "format" option in the definition of the column.

Comment: It's in its template (`DefaulCellStyle`)

Comment: OK, So yes, that does answer my question. but interestingly there is no "Format" that shows up when using Intellisense, So it didn't seem like it was an option.